# Laravel 5 User Model not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have moved the User model from the default app directory into app/Models.

I have updated the namespace in User to `namespace App\Models;` but I am getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 122:
Class '\App\User' not found
```

I have the correct entry in my json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Modules",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Modules\\": "app/Modules/"
    }
},
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @fakemeta yes, still gives the error :(

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve user object using laravel authentication or are you instantiating it manually?

Comment: @fakemeta I'm just trying to get the start pages that are provided out of the box it work. When I try to log in, it gives me that error.

Comment: Also a note: I think the second line in the `psr-4` section of your  `autoload` block is redundant.

Comment: @MartinBean Doesn't that simply provide a short hand way of setting the namespace for my controllers etc under modules? So instead of App/Modules I can just go Modules/

Comment: @imperium2335 No. It’s saying, “Look in app/Modules for the namespace Modules”. You’ll still need to use the full namespace, i.e. `App\Modules`.

Comment: Is good to mention that in the case you move the User model you also need to change it's namespace: <?php namespace App\Models;

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You need to update your **config/auth.php** file. Change `'model' => 'App\User'` to `'model' => 'App\Models\User'`.

Comment: Worked for me.  How did you find this out?

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget to clear cache after all previous changes

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget to change your `User.php` namespace.

E.g. If your User model is located at `/App/User.php` then the first line should read:

```
<?php namespace App;
```

However, if you've created a `/Models` directory and your User model is now located at `/App/Models/User.php`, the first line of User.php should reference this new namespace:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

*** Note: My tactic is probably technically 'incorrect' as it pollutes the global namespace.  However, I had trouble getting the other answers working and post this only as a last resort. ***

I did this a slightly different way than the other answers.  I'm also using Laravel 5.

1) I created the app/Models directory and moved User.php into that directory.

2) I modified /app/Models/User.php by removing the namespace at the top.  This might be polluting the global namespace, but it's the only way I could get it working.

```
<?php  // !!!! NOTICE no namespace here  !!!!!

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

}
```

3) I added "app/Models" to my autoload section in composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"    // <==== I added this               
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

4) I modified auth.php as follows:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Model
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
| Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
| is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
|
*/

'model' => '\User',
```

For reference, here's my users table migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

And here's my UsersTableSeeder.php file:

```
<?PHP

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        $users = [
            [ 'id' => 1, 'first_name' => 'Bret', 'last_name' => 'Lastname', 'email' => 'email@domain.com', 'password' => Hash::make('my raw dev password')]
        ];

        foreach($users as $user){
            \User::create($user);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

After all of those updates were done, on the command line I ran:

```
composer dump-autoload 
php artisan migrate --seed
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: “This might be polluting the global namespace, but it's the only way I could get it working.” Not if you followed other answers, including mine.

Comment: I understand your downvote.  I had tried the other answers previous to posting my own and couldn't get them to work.  I'll modify my answer to recommend that people try the other techniques before mine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change

```
use App\User;
```

to

```
use App\Models\User;
```

in the AuthController.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have your models in a specific folder, then you need to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to refresh :)