# Laravel 5.1 Class '\App\User' not found, FatalErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 126

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I moved my `User` Model from `App\User` to `App\Models\Users`, I followed the proper instruction, the same thing working properly on Windows OS, while facing error on `Ubuntu 14.04`

Whenever I try to `Login(When submit information)` it gives me error

> FatalErrorException in
>   /var/www/html/sms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php
>
> line 126: Class '\App\User' not found

I also run `composer dump-autoload` command, but no luck. 
Also tried this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28516582/1216451

Here is my settings for `Models` directory

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

**Model Directory Structure**
`App/Models/`

**Model** `User.php`

```
namespace App\Models;
```

**Auth.php** tried both lines, given below.

```
'model' => App\Models\User::class,
'model' => App\Models\User,
```

**AuthController.php**

```
use App\Models\User;
```

**EloquentUserProvider.php** path is `sms/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php line 126`

```
public function createModel()
{
    $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');

    return new $class; //line# 126
}
```

Comment: I followed your linked reference, which is what i needed, then I  realized I  needed to set `auth.php` to `'model' => App\Models\User\User::class,`, or in your case `App\Models\Users\User::class`. I suspect this was what you were missing?  I missed the 2nd User entry there at first too because my dir is actually called singular `User`.    That solved it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your configurations seems accurate, just reset them by using `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Please check also all those files including relationship
the perfect way find out all, is to search folder excluding vendor.

```
config/services.php
config/auth.php
database\factories\Userfactory.php

public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have specified the correct namespace.

Like

App\Models\User
but this depend on youe file construction some time users but the Model User inside folder that named Models in older versions of laravel  cus it's not there by default

Comment: PLEASE DON'T ANSWER IN ALL CAPS. It's hard to read and looks like you're shouting. Please also expand your answer so that it's easier for anyone of all skill levels to understand what you are suggesting they should do.

Comment: I'm sorry for that I re edit my answer and didn't notice that my CapsLock is on